# My function works just once

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, validation

I have a problem with my function. I want to make a login form validation by JSON data. My code works fine, but only when I put correct data just after refresh. For example, when I enter incorrect login/password I receive error, but after that when I type correct login/password nothing happens.

I'll be very grateful if you can help. Here is my js code:

```
//JSON validation
function validation(username, password){
    var alert = document.getElementById("invalid-data");
    data = JSON.parse(data);

    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (username == data[i].login && password == data[i].password) {
            window.open("panel.html", "_self");
        } else {
            alert.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}

//Form validation
function getLoginInfo() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    validation(username, password);
}

var button = document.getElementById("login-button");
button.addEventListener("click", getLoginInfo);
```

Comment: What error do you get in your error console?

Comment: Where is `data` defined? `data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: My data is defined in external file - data/users.json.

Comment: I receive error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at validation (main.js:4)
    at HTMLButtonElement.getLoginInfo (main.js:20)

Comment: i hope your problem is `data = JSON.parse(data);` because when first time you get parse `data` you put it into `data` again and it cause problem in your next `data` json parsing.

Comment: Once you've done `data = JSON.parse(data);` once, it will never work again.

Comment: You should parse the JSON when you read the file, not every time you call the function.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! I made data global and everything works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope your problem is `data = JSON.parse(data);` because when first time you get parse data you put it into `data` again and it cause problem in your next `data` json parsing. so i think your problem would be solve if you put your parsed `data` into different variable like code bellow:

```
//JSON validation
function validation(username, password){
var alert = document.getElementById("invalid-data");
var parsed_data = JSON.parse(data);

for (var i=0; i < parsed_data.length; i++) {
    if (username == parsed_data[i].login && password == parsed_data[i].password) {
        window.open("panel.html", "_self");
    } else {
        alert.style.display = "block";
    }
}
}
//Form validation
function getLoginInfo() {
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

validation(username, password);
}

var button = document.getElementById("login-button");
button.addEventListener("click", getLoginInfo);
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. That was the problem, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

So, problem of this function was that

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

was inside a function. I made it global and everything works fine.